# I have an error in running my app on devices and emulator, showing some errors on logcat

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to Android programming and I'm using Android Studio. I am creating an app which consists of periodic table of elements and its trends. Currently, I'm having trouble with regards to running the app on devices and emulator. By the way I'm not using the built-in emulator of android studio since I'm using AMD processor. I haven't done anything in my mainactivity.java. Specifically, when I open my app in devices and emulator(using bluestacks) it would just open with a white screen and closes immediately.

---

Some of my PC specs:
AMD processor dual core 2.7Ghz
2gb RAM

---

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

Some of my XML codes:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:id="@+id/H"
        android:background="@drawable/hydrogen1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:id="@+id/Li"
        android:background="@drawable/lithium1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:id="@+id/Na"
        android:background="@drawable/sodium1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:id="@+id/K"
        android:background="@drawable/potassium1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        />
```

---

Here are the errors in my logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jd.betatest/com.example.jd.betatest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #866: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #866: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
_____________________
```

---

I tried modifying my studio.exe in bin
here are the values:

```
-server
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio
```

Studio64.exe values:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio
```

Comment: try use https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

Comment: Didn't work for me sir